# template in directive doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS and am learning directives. I used the tutorials from egghead.io and am stuck with the following example:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "../libs/angular/angular.js" ></script >
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "example.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="phoneApp">
        <div ng-controller="phoneCtrl">
           <phoneDir></phoneDir>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example.js contains this:

```
var app = angular.module('phoneApp',[]);

app.controller('phoneCtrl',function($scope) {

});

app.directive('phoneDir',function() {
    return {
        restrict:"E",
        template:'<div> Panel </div>'
   }    
})
```

Its a very simple example that's just trying to use a directive in the HTML The problem is I don't see the div having the 'Panel' defined in the template. Can someone help?

Comment: use `<phone-dir>` directives are camelCase just in the code, they are hyphenated in the markup

Comment: @doodeec: Yes, that solved it. if you can post this as an answer, I'll close this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directives use camelCase name only in the code, markup uses hyphenated names

use

```
<phone-dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the replace: true property.  I think that will solve your issue.

```
app.directive('phoneDir',function() {
return {
    restrict:"E",
    replace: true,
    template:'<div> Panel </div>'
 }    
})
```

Comment: replacing just sets, whether to add template inside the tag, or show it instead of tag in markup

Comment: doodeec is exactly right.  I totally overlooked that.  You need to hyphenate the element's name in the markup, instead of using camel case (only in the HTML).